# Find last index of element in list with duplicate elements python

Tags: python

I have a list like this : [1,12,3,4,4,5,12,15,13,11]

I want to find index of 12 i.e 6.
I have tried linear approach but it is not efficient.

```
item = 12
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] == item:
        index = i
return index
```

Any efficient way to get this ?

Comment: `return` is outside of function

Comment: What is wrong with a linear approach? You could approach from the right, maybe. But the solution is fundamentally linear. So what do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: What i mean by efficient is can we apply binary search for this ?

Comment: @KishanMehta no, not unless it is ordered. Then yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go from right to left:

```
mylist = [1,12,3,4,4,5,12,15,13,11]
item = 12
for i in range(len(mylist)-1,-1,-1):
    if mylist[i] == item:
        index = i
        print(index)
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

```
len(mylist) - list(reversed(mylist)).index(item) -  1
```

will be enough

Comment: The last occurrence, not the first.

Comment: OK, reverse it. See my changes

Comment: you need to convert the index back to the regular indexing, not the "reversed" indexing.

Comment: You must be kidding me. It's really insolvable problem... reverse the index??? how???

Comment: this will gie `AttributeError: 'listreverseiterator' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: fix
`len(mylist) - list(reversed(mylist)).index(item) -  1`

Answer (score 2):

The last occurrence of an element in a list is same as the first occurrence of that element in the reversed list.

So the index of last occurrence of an element in original list is equal to (length_of_list - index_in_reversed_list - 1).

You can use the `list.reverse()` method to reverse the list and then find the index of first occurrence of the required element in reversed list by `list.index()` method.

For example:

```
>>> mylist = [1,12,3,4,4,5,12,15,13,11]
>>> temp = mylist[:]
>>> temp.reverse()
>>> index = len(temp) - temp.index(12) - 1
>>> print(index)
6
```

Comment: How is this more "efficient" than the OPs solution?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the help. I did not notice that. My mistake. But I corrected it now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It may not be as much more efficient than the OPs solution, but it provides an elegant way to solve the problem using inbuilt python functions that are anyday faster than your own implementation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Noted. Thanks again

Comment: With most optimize way with respect to time and space complexity:
Step-1: Start travelling the original array from last, 
Step-2: Once you find the given element.
Step-3: Return the index = l - i -1; where l = total length of the array, i = index of the element in step-2.